# Bind 1 GridView to sql connection string array

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I need to run the same SQL query for multiply SQL servers and get the result
into one grid view.

The result that i am getting is only for one database connection server,
How to repeat the grid view for both servers ? 
Thanks all,

web config:

```
     <connectionStrings>
      <add name="db1" connectionString="my connection string for server 1" />
      <add name="db2" connectionString="my connection string for server 2" />
    </connectionStrings>
```

asp.net:

```
     <div>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"></asp:GridView>
    </div>
```

c#:

```
string[] arr = new string[2] { "db1", "db2" };

    arr[0] = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["db1"].ConnectionString;
    arr[1] = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["db2"].ConnectionString;

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(arr[i]);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * from some sys.dm", con);
        con.Open();
        GridView1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        GridView1.DataBind();
        con.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic right now will overwrite your first datasource with your second. You instead would want to combine the two datasources and bind them as one to your GridView.

Try something like this:

```
DataTable dtFinal = new DataTable();
foreach (string conString in arr)
{
    DataTable dtTemp = new DataTable();

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * from some sys.dm", con))
        {
            con.Open();

            dtTemp.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
            dtFinal.Merge(dtTemp);
        }
    }
}

GridView1.DataSource = dtFinal;
GridView1.DataBind();
```